# How to stop ipython autocompletion to generate a space at the end?

Tags: ipython

When using ipython in a console interactive session, pressing tab will generate autocompletions, but always generate an additional space character after the text. Can I change this behavior and make the autocompletion only generate the remaining text for the word?

Comment: This is most likely a bug of your configuration (probably readline). Which os, version(s) of software(s), have looked if it is [reproducible on pure python](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ipython/+bug/470824), or try the [anaonda solutions?](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/anaconda/oRV1Yc-H3IY)... etc

Comment: I am actually using anaconda's ipython. (Python 2.7.5) Anaconda 1.8.0 (64bit). My shell's autocompletion works fine. If I only open the python interface, there is no autocompletion function.Do you know where I can check my autocompletion configuration for ipython?

Comment: if it's anaconda, no, I have clue, try asking on the chat of continuum.io

Comment: I have the same problem on Anaconda 1.8.0 (64bit). Been using IPython for a long time and never had this before on any other version.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known and still-active bug [Issue42](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/42)